# web.py, How to share the base_base_template among subapps?

Tags: web.py

In order to reduce the superfluous codes，I want to share a base template among many 
subapps,

***Example dir tree***

```
├── admin
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── admin.html
│   └── view.py
├── base_templates
│   └── base.html
└── view.py
```

Now , I am using dir package styel as a sub app(I dunno whether it's a right way to do this). Above,
I am going to use base.html template in admin app, so

***foo.py***

```webctx
render = web.template.render(...) # the render
class Foo:
    def GET:
        return render.admin()
```

any way to resolve my trouble ? thx

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a [site layout template](http://webpy.org/cookbook/layout_template).

Comment: link only questions are frowned upon as the links tend to go dead! If you could figure out how to work in some actual content that would be helpful.